# Why does set state only work once within a subscription to an observable?

Tags: react-hooks, rxjs

I'm now learning rxjs and want to use it in react.But there is a question confuse me.Below is a piece of code which I want to setstate in the subscription,but it only work once when mousedown is triggered.So when I click down the mouse and move it, the inputbox can only change once,just when I click.

```
export default function RxjsTest () {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0)
  const [y, setY] = useState(0)
  const divRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
const mouseDown$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, 'mousedown');
const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, 'mousemove');
const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, 'mouseup');

const subscription = mouseDown$
  .pipe(
    tap((x) => console.log(x.type)),
    exhaustMap((start) =>
      mouseMove$.pipe(
        tap((x) => console.log(x.type)),
        takeUntil(mouseUp$)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(event => { setX(event.clientX); setY(event.clientY) });
return () => {
  subscription.unsubscribe()
}
})
return <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', backgroundColor: 'pink' }} ref= 
   {divRef}>
<input value={x} ></input>
</div>
}
```

but the code below can get every value of the mousemove and set it to the state.So the inputbox can keep changing if my mouse has moved.

```
export default function RxjsTest () {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0)
  const [y, setY] = useState(0)
  const divRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
   const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, 'mousemove');

   const subscription = mouseMove$.pipe(tap(console.log)).subscribe(event => { 
   setX(event.clientX); setY(event.clientY) })
  return () => {
  subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
 })
return <div style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', backgroundColor: 'pink' }} ref= 
 {divRef}>
  <input value={x} ></input>
 </div>
}
```

Is there any problem with the first code.Thanks for anyone can help me.

Comment: Maybe [this blog](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/88d2789e408a) about reactive programming with react can help

Answer (score 0):

Every time you set the state, the `useEffect` function will re-run, unsubscribing from the previous observable, creating a new observable and re-subscribing.

If you pass in an empty dependency array into the second parameter of the `useEffect` I think it *should* work.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const mouseDown$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, "mousedown");
  const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, "mousemove");
  const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(divRef.current, "mouseup");

  const subscription = mouseDown$
    .pipe(
      tap((x) => console.log(x.type)),
      exhaustMap((start) =>
        mouseMove$.pipe(
          tap((x) => console.log(x.type)),
          takeUntil(mouseUp$)
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe((event) => {
      setX(event.clientX);
      setY(event.clientY);
    });
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []); // <-- this parameter
```

Note that this could not work if you're using Suspense with React, because of how HTMLElement refs work. To build something that's safer you'd have to create callback refs and do some extra logic to avoid creating new observables when it's not needed.